# sqlite make test fails because of "tcl.h not found" or "undefined reference to Tcl_Free"

Tags: compiling, sqlite, tcl

I have obtained the sqlite source code with:

```
sudo apt-get install fossil
mkdir sqlite
cd sqlite
fossil clone http://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/doc/trunk a
fossil open a
rm a
```

and compiled it [with the instructions on the README](http://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/doc/trunk/README.md). Now I want to run `make test`.

The README says that that requires Tcl development files. On Ubuntu 14.04 I run:

```
sudo apt-get install tcl8.6-dev
```

Then if I `make test` it gave `tcl.h not found`

So I located `tcl.h` and run:

```
CPATH="$CPATH:/usr/include/tcl8.6" make test
```

But now it gives:

```
/tmp/cc4jwHgX.o: In function `dbFreeStmt':
/home/ciro/git/sqlite/./src/tclsqlite.c:451: undefined reference to `Tcl_Free'
/tmp/cc4jwHgX.o: In function `closeIncrblobChannels':
/home/ciro/git/sqlite/./src/tclsqlite.c:189: undefined reference to `Tcl_UnregisterChann

 ...
```

I have tried:

```
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo ln -s libtcl8.6.so libtcl.so
```

with not success.

Comment: I suggest you ask on StackOverflow -- that's where the Tcl experts are.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly where/how you got the source? I unpacked and configured the (latest) sqlite-autoconf-3080704.tar.gz file from the site you linked but the Makefile doesn't appear to have a `test` target. BTW why do you need to build sqlite from source at all?

Comment: @steeldriver added clone method. I'm pretty sure `make test` exists since it runs (and fails), and since the README says it exists. I'm compiling it to learn database internals.

Comment: I think maybe you should have installed the `tcl-dev` meta package instead of the specific `tcl8.6-dev` version package - it appears to include a `/usr/lib/tcl-Config.sh` script that sources a suitable Tcl build environment. I was able to `make` and `make test` without modifying anything.

Comment: @steeldriver thanks for the tip. It definitely is the better package, as it contains the symlinks to the 8.6 version, but I still get the same errors: the include would need to be `tcl/tcl.h` to work. The `.so` is now there, but I get the same link errors as before :(

Comment: @steeldriver ah, I've cloned again and restarted the process and it works the problem is that I hadn't recompiled... Please add your `tcl-dev` comment as an answer and get 25 rep :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sqlite configure script appears to look for a Tcl installation as follows:

```
checking for Tcl configuration... found /usr/lib/tclConfig.sh
checking for existence of /usr/lib/tclConfig.sh... loading
```

This shell script sources a suitable environment such as `INCLUDE` and `LIB` directives, but **it is provided by the `tcl-dev` meta package**, rather than the specific `tcl8.6-dev` package that you installed.

If you install the `tcl-dev` meta package and do a clean build then the Tcl components should be located without any need to set other variables in the `make` command.

The `tclConfig.sh` script seems to be Tcl's own equivalent of the more generic `pkg-config` mechanism.

Comment: after installing tcl-dev we need to run `./configure` again, then `make` and `make test`